# How to define informative priors in rstanarm?

Tags: stan, rstan, rstanarm

I have use some binomial count data and have run stan_glm using the default prior.
I'm interested in getting the odds ratio (OR) and 95% credible intervals.
This works well with the default vague priors.

```
library(rstan) 
library(rstanarm)
library(bayesplot)
library(tidyverse)

# drug A (grp2=0) had 10 good outcomes among 62 patients 
# drug B (grp2=1)had 14 good outcomes among 70 patients 
data_bin2 <- data.frame(N = c(62,70), y = c(10,14), grp2 = c(0,1))

fit_bin <- stan_glm(y/N ~ grp2, family = binomial(), data = data_bin2,
                weights = N, seed = 123, refresh = 0)
monitor(fit_bin$stanfit)
prior_summary(fit_bin) #show the default priors which seem to be log based

draws_bin <- as.data.frame(fit_bin) %>%
  mutate(theta1 = plogis(`(Intercept)`),
         theta2 = plogis(`(Intercept)` + grp2),
         oddsratio = (theta2/(1-theta2))/(theta1/(1-theta1)))
mcmc_hist(draws_bin, pars='oddsratio', binwidth = .01)

mcmc_median <- median(draws_bin$oddsratio)
mcmc_ci95 <- round(posterior_interval(as.matrix(draws_bin), prob = 0.95, pars = "oddsratio"),2)
```

But I would also like to use the following data from a previous study as informative priors -

drug A had 1 good outcomes among 15 patients
drug B had 6 good outcomes among 14 patients
and here I'm uncertain how to proceed.

Presumably I use the arguments `prior_intercept =` and `prior =` but does the `prior_intercept` require only the drug A data (grp2=0) and `prior` only uses drug B data (grp2=1)? Or do I assign the prior OR to the `prior_intercept` function?
Also most commonly I have seen `prior_intercept = normal(mean, scale)`. I can use the normal approximation to this binomial data but with small sample sizes this seems unsatisfactory. I don't think a `binomial ()` exists in `rstanarm`. Also are the `mean` and `scale` log transformed before being used by these functions?
Any help on precisely showing how to incorporate this prior binomial information would be much appreciated.